# eqs on Option[UUID] type? Phantom + Cassandra + Scala

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I'm using Phantom framework to work with Cassandra and I'm trying to do a eqs on a Option field eg.

```
Address.select.where(_.id eqs Some(uuid)).one()
```

Then I get "value eqs is not a member of object"

is there a way to accomplish that? I can't figure out...

The id field is an Option[UUID], because it must be null when I'm receiving a POST request in Play Framework, but I don't know how to do this assert in phantom

I also opened an issue on github.

https://github.com/websudos/phantom/issues/173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phantom relies on a series of implicit conversions to provide most of the functionality. A very simple way to fix most of the errors you get from compiling phantom tables is to make sure the relevant import is in scope.

Before phantom 1.7.0

```
import com.websudos.phantom.Implicits._
```

After 1.7.0

```
import com.websudos.phantom.dsl._
```

Beyond the implicit mechanism, phantom will also help you with aliases to a vast number of useful objects in Cassandra:

- Phantom connectors
- Cassandra Consistency Levels
- Keyspaces

Using a potentially `null` value as part of a `PRIMARY KEY` in CQL is also wrong as no part of the CQL primary can be `null`. It's a much better idea to move processing logic outside of phantom.

Traditionally, a tables -> db service -> api controller -> api approach is the way to build modular applications with better separation of concerns. It's best to keep simple I/O at table level, app level consistency at db service level, and all processing logic at a higher level.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using the

```
import com.websudos.phantom.Implicits._
```

works!!!